# NHibernate ignores length attribute

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

After running SQL Profiler, I realized that NHibernate was mapping strings to `nvarchar(4000)`. I fixed it by specifying `type=AnsiString and length=...` in the hbm file. It is now generating `varchar(8000)` statements, and it is ignoring the length. How come?

hbm file:

```
<property name="EmailAddress" column="EMAIL_ADDRESS" type="AnsiString" length="120" />
```

database field:

```
[EMAIL_ADDRESS] [varchar](120) NULL,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually in previous versions of nhibernate the check against length was implemented also for query creation.

But, the current implementation of the SqlDriver got a change last year, 
see https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3036 for details of the fix.

Bugfix:

```
    // Used from SqlServerCeDriver as well
    public static void SetVariableLengthParameterSize(IDbDataParameter dbParam, SqlType sqlType)
    {
        SetDefaultParameterSize(dbParam, sqlType);

        // no longer override the defaults using data from SqlType, since LIKE expressions needs larger columns
        // https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3036
        //if (sqlType.LengthDefined && !IsText(dbParam, sqlType) && !IsBlob(dbParam, sqlType))
        //{
        //  dbParam.Size = sqlType.Length;
        //}

        if (sqlType.PrecisionDefined)
        {
            dbParam.Precision = sqlType.Precision;
            dbParam.Scale = sqlType.Scale;
        }
    }
```

The defaults are what you see (4000/8000) dependent on the data type...

Comment: I'm not sure if you are suggesting that I update my NHibernate. I did upgrade to 3.3.3 and it suffers from the same problem.

Comment: I'm saying that nhibernate will ignore the length attribute for building queries by design, since the bugfix I posted, which is answering your question *is ignoring the length. How come?!* To verify you do not exceed the string length on insert/update, simply use validation instead

Comment: Thanks, but it's not the insert/update that worries me. It's the select that bothers me. I know for sure that my inserts have short data, but when you do a select, don't you allocate a buffer of 8000 bytes for this query? (or 4000 considering SQL Server does some parameter estimation)

Comment: @MrTibs that's something I'm not sure about if SQL Server would optimize it or not. But anyways, you cannot do anything for it. That's how it is currently implemented in nhibernate and you cannot change this by yourself at all ;)

Comment: I spoke to my dba and he's saying that it might not be too bad, since the execution plan does get bigger, but it is only one execution plan. We'll run some tests to see the memory allocated for each run. Thanks a lot!