# Why is the generated SQL declaring parameters of 8000 or 4000 in length instead of the length specified in the mapping?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, nhibernate, conventions

NHibernate varchar and nchar length mapping is ignored, when varchar field used with NHibernate convention

Instead of mapping varchar to the values in the mapping they are mapping to varchar(8000) and nchar(4000) this is causing an update to take a very long time, and subsequently blocking other updates.

We are using:

Microsoft SQL Server 2016

FluentNHibernate Version 1.3.0.0

NHibernate Version 3.3.1.4000

```
public UserMap()
{
    Table("User")
    Id(x=>x.Id, "User_ID")
    Map(x=>x.User_refNo, "User_refNo").Length(255).Nullable();
    Map(x=>x.Name,"Name").Length(100).Nullable();
    Map(x=>x.Gender,"Sex").Nullable();
}
```

Generated SQL Update

```
@p0 AnsiString(8000),
@p1 AnsiString(8000),
@p2 nchar(4000),
@p3 int;
UPDATE dbo.User SET
 User_refNo = @p0,
 Name = @p1,
 Sex = @p2 WHERE User_ID = @p3
```

To add this is has something to do with the varchar type and PropertyConventions

```
public void Apply(IPropertyInstance instance)
{
    if (instance.Property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        instance.CustomType("AnsiString");
}
```

If I change the convention with the following the mapping is improved:

```
public void Apply(IPropertyInstance instance)
{
   if (instance.Type == typeof(string))
   {
        instance.CustomSqlType($"varchar ({2000})");
   }
}
```

Now the SQL generated, looks like this:

```
@p0 String(4000),
@p1 String(4000),
@p2 String(4000),
@p3 int;
UPDATE dbo.User SET
 User_refNo = @p0,
 Name = @p1,
 Sex = @p2 WHERE User_ID = @p3
```

However we require the AnsiString type.

Comment: What is the question? If the field's length is 4000, the field's length is 4000. If it's 100, it's 100. The *parameter's* size shouldn't matter at all. 8000 is the maximum size of a (var)char column, 4000 the max for n(var)char. Looks like NH is using the max size for the parameters. This *doesn't* matter

Comment: The question is why is the generated SQL declaring parameters of 8000 or 4000 in length instead of the length specified in the mapping?

Comment: again, I repeat, what is the problem? What does it matter what the *parameter* size is*? Is the generated table wrong? Are large strings getting truncated without warning? Is validation ignored?

Comment: BTW 1) the statement is generated by NHibernate, not Fluent NHibernate. It would be a valid Fluent NH question if NH mappings resulted in different behaviour. 2) NH is essentially abandoned. Perhaps someone decided it's OK to use the maximum type size for *parameters* 7 years ago, as long as validation worked. This isn't going to change anytime soon

Comment: Finally, this has nothing to do with the varchar type or property conventions. What you typed in this question is actually a **serious bug**. You are saving **Unicode** strings as **ANSI**. This **guarantees** convertion problems and even data loss. The only problem in the posted code is the `Apply` method

Comment: Are you saying I am introducing a bug with 'varchar(2000)' or that NHibernate has a bug?

Comment: I'm saying that *you* are introducing a bug by specifying that `string`, a Unicode type, should be mapped to varchar, an ANSI type, using an *arbitrary* codepage, that of the current system's locale

Comment: Instead of trying to "fix" what isn't broken, why do you care how long the *parameter* is? Did you encounter an actual problem? Did you try using NH mappings instead of Fluent NH? Is the behaviour of NH vs Fluent NH different? This could be a non-issue or a minor Fluent NH bug

Comment: Ok @Panagiotis Kanavos thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate:
[NHibernate ignores length attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20111457/nhibernate-ignores-length-attribute)

and an earlier one with the same reply:
[Fluent NHibernate mapping to a SQL Server CHAR(10) ID column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059233/fluent-nhibernate-mapping-to-a-sql-server-char10-id-column)

Basically, NH ignores the length in the queries and parameters and uses the default. So String is always nvarchar(4000) and AnsiString varchar(8000).

My similar issue is mapping a Gender column to a char(1), and NH with a query such as this:

```
return GetNamedQuery("xxxxxxx")
    .SetAnsiString("name", name)
    //.SetParameter("gender", gender, NHibernateUtil.AnsiChar) //char version
    .SetCharacter("gender", gender) //nchar version
```

Generates SQL such as this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'select ... where ... Name=@p3 and ... Gender=@p5',
N'... @p3 varchar(8000),... @p5 char(8000)',... @p3='NAME GOES HERE'...,
@p5='M               [padding with 7999 spaces here ]                        ',@p6=0
```

Seems wrong to me, and also generates extra chargeable network traffic between instances in a cloud environment. SQL query plan doesn't seem affected.

NH bug, still opened: https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3403